# JQuery Isotope - Images missing on PC but show on Phone

Tags: jquery, css, image, position

I created an Isotope Portfolio a few years back and all was working fine. Recently I have been checking it on my phone and all fine, however, I have just looked at it on my PC and all the images are missing. Anyone know if there has been an update in PC browsers that would cause this please? If I remove the element * {position:absolute} they come back but incorrectly positioned so this is not the answer.
Any help much appreciated:
http://playboxdesign.co.uk/portfolio.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` tag in the isotope element is position absolutely as well as the image in it.

Add `width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the `a` tag in order stretch the element and it will fix itself.